# Update attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a table A(:name, :age). I want to update the age attribute to 30 from the default value of -1 and it should be saved in the database. I am writing this command in the rails console.

```
A.find(300).update_attribute(:age, 30)
```

But, this isn't working. What is wrong?

I tried the below too :

```
u = A.find(300)
u.age = 30
u.save
```

But, this also doesn't work. u.save returns false with the database rollback trace.

Comment: The syntax is correct. What error do you get? Maybe there's no record with id of 300?

Comment: The database rollbacks with a very big HTML output.

Comment: You probably have validation errors. What do `u.valid?` and `u.errors` return?

Comment: Got it solved. Was an internal issue with a callback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try saving with bypassing validations.

```
u = A.find(300)
u.age = 30
u.save(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this . may helpful for you

```
A.update(300, {:age => 30})
```